# Why is the about detail so incorrectfor gis se

Tags: discussion, tour

I was just checking the [about](https://gis.stackexchange.com/about) of GIS SE and I found the about details completely irrelevant to GIS.

Should it not describe more about the details of GIS?

Comment: The 'about' page is a generic SE page. You probably want to be reading our [faq](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: FAQs are good but shouldn't each about page be descriptive specific to  forum. Why is it generic?

Comment: @Sam007 Which particular details did you find irrelevant?

Comment: Huh @R.K., actually there is nothing relevant in the about page for GIS. It has the same Venn Diagramm which is no way related to the GIS. What did u find relevant in the about page for GIS?

Comment: Are moderators even able to edit this page?

Comment: The "About" page now redirects to the [Tour] so I think this question is now obsolete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The About Page is for information about the GIS StackExchange site, not about GIS.

The current GIS SE About Page states who the site is for

> This is a free, community driven Q&A for cartographers, geographers
>   and GIS professionals. It is a part of the Stack Exchange network of
>   Q&A websites, and it was created through the open democratic process
>   defined at Stack Exchange Area 51.

what sets it apart from other sites and how you may use it.

[image]

I think it's a good about page.